# Unable to successfully format a secondary HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, formatting, hdd

I installed a secondary HDD in my MacBook Pro in the CD drive tray using a caddy. In my main drive slot I have an SSD which works fine. The 500GB drive I had before, I decided to put in the caddy and replace the CD drive with it.

I can't format my secondary HDD using Disk Utility through the command line tool. I keep getting stuck on "Waiting for partitions to activate" when trying to format using Disk Utility.

[image]

Here is some info from the command line I got on the drive:

[image]

[image]

It seems like it has no partitions. Here's more info from `gpt`:

[image]

[image]

I also ran `testdisk` analysis on the disk:

[image]

What should I do? I used to have this disk in an external caddy and used as a backup HD but I wanted it back in my Mac since I needed more space.

**UPDATE 1**
I've tried the following, as suggested by one of the comments.

[image]

Comment: Tried `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk2 count=1 bs=512` already? You may also use count=40 to nullify any partition table content. Check the proper disk identifier with `diskutil list` first! Then destroy and create a new GUID pt with `sudo gpt destroy ...` and `sudo gpt create -f ...`.

Comment: @klanomath I have and got `Input/output error` in both cases.

Comment: Then I would suspect the cable or the connectors to be faulty (or not properly connected)! Which kind of MBP do you exactly have? Some with a 3GBit/s SATA link for the DVD drive don't work properly with 6GBit/s HDDs.

Comment: @klanomath I have the `MacBookPro9,2`. I think you might be right with the speed thing. When I look into System Report and under SATA, and select the port which has the new HDD, I see `Link Speed: 6 Gigabit` and `Negotiated Link Speed: 3 Gigabit` while for the SSD that is in the main bay that works, I see `6 Gigabit` for both.

Comment: Hmm I don't know. At least the [HTS545050A7E362](http://www.hdsentinel.com/storageinfo_details.php?lang=en&model=HITACHI%20HTS545050A7E362) provides a SATAII (3 GBit/s) interface only.

Comment: @klanomath I'll try ordering a new SATA 3GB/s HDD (probably [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Toshiba-MQ01ABD100-5400RPM-9-5mm-Internal/dp/B009AYVNMQ/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1480085219&sr=8-1&keywords=2.5%2Binch%2Bsata%2B3%2Bgb&th=1)) and if that doesn't work them I'm guessing its either the cable or the connector.